# ES6 class proxy immutable

Tags: proxy, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Hey i am trying to create a class instance, which is immutable object.
So i was thinking to use proxies.

I want each time a developer will try to change the object properties, 
a new object will be deep cloned from the current object.
and the result will be this new object with the changes.
its important the class proto will stay available.

**Example**:

```
class Men{
  constructor(name){
    this.schema = {prop: {innerProp:{}}}; 
    this.name = name;
  }
set newName(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

var handler = {
  set (target, key, value) {
      target =  new Proxy(_.cloneDeep(target), this);
      target[key] = value;
      return target // Return the new obj with the change
    }
};

let jeson = new Men("jeson");

let jesonProxy = new Proxy(jeson, handler);

// Taking the new jeson proxy with the change
let newJesonProxy = (jesonProxy.schema = {newProp: {newInnerProp: {}}});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to do my example correctly

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use a proxy for this, and setters not either. They do not allow you to change the result of the assignment. Use an ordinary method for creating the changed instances, and simply freeze the objects.

```
class Man {
  constructor(name) {
    this.schema = {prop: {innerProp:{}}}; 
    this.name = name;
    Object.freeze(this);
  }
  withName(name) {
    return new this.constructor(name);
  }
}

const x = new Man("");
const y = x.withName("jeson");
```